# Is there any way to run mysql json function in another function?

Tags: mysql

This is my SQL query. Is there any way to run it in a single "SELECT QUERY,UPDATE QUERY"?

table data :-

+++++++++++++
columnname
++++++++++++++

{"family": ["a", "b", "c"]}

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

{"family": ["d", "e", "f"]}

+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

{"family": ["b", "e", "f"]}

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

```
SELECT JSON_REPLACE(columnname, JSON_SEARCH(columnname, 'one', 'a'), "{'a': 1}") FROM tablename;


UPDATE tablename
SET columnname= JSON_REPLACE(columnname, JSON_SEARCH(columnname, 'one', 'a'), '{"a": 1}')
WHERE product_id != id;
```

Comment: Why do you need it in a single query?

Comment: i want to replace json value with another json value
eg. "family": ["a", "b", "c", "d"]
JSON_REPLACE(family,JSON_SEARCH(family,'one','a'),"{'a':1}")

Comment: Please frame SQL questions with **relevant and minimal sample data** showcasing your requirements, and **corresponding expected output**. Please read this link: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/333952/2469308)

Comment: The result you want is: `{"family": ["{a: 1}", "b", "c"]}`?.

Comment: yes you are right. like {"family": ["{a: 1}", "b", "c"]}

Comment: Try: `JSON_REPLACE(columnname, JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_SEARCH(columnname, 'one', 'a', NULL, '$.family[*]')), JSON_OBJECT('a', 1))`.

Comment: Thanks @wchiquito what you suggested. it works